# CPLEX: how to construct excel data for tuple keys

Tags: cplex

My model has two tuples: Lot and Stp.

```
 tuple Lot{key int id; int n; float w}
 tuple Stp{key Lot l; key int pos; int f;}

 {Lot} Lots = ...;
 {Stp} Stps = ...;
```

Tuple Stp uses items from Tuple Lot (Lot l) as one of its elements.
Currently, I am reading data from .dat file, and the data looks like this:

```
Lots = {<1, 60, 0.4>, <2, 30, 0.8>...};
Stps = {<<1, 60, 0.4>, 1, 1>,
        <<1, 60, 0.4>, 2, 2>,...};
```

It works just fine. However, I would like to create an excel file to store these data and read from excel file instead. But I don't know how to deal with the first element in Stps. I tried several ways:

1. enter <1, 60, 0.4> to one cell as the first element
   [trial1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJG32.jpg)
2. enter 1 60 0.4 to one cell as the first element
   [trial2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtCPb.jpg)
3. enter 1 (as the key in Lot) to one cell as the first element
   [trial3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJB1I.jpg)
   None of these work.
   Can anybody help me how to save data in excel when one of the elements is a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SheetConnection s("readtuplekeys.xlsx");

Lots from SheetRead(s,"A1:C2");
Stps from SheetRead(s,"E1:I2");
```

works fine.

Full example :

- https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readtuplekeys.mod
- https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readtuplekeys.dat
- https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readtuplekeys.xlsx